# Array en el template de Angular

Tags: html, array, typescript, angular, angular2-template

Tengo el siguiente código en ts, donde muestra un código, el cual consiste en que, cada que le doy click a un botón; me va a disminuir un array y cuando quede un sólo array, no me lo borre; sino que lo muestre por más que le de click en el botón.

```
removeCostCenter() { 
    if (this.costCenter[+1]) {
      let pos = this.costCenter.indexOf(name);
      this.costCenter.splice(pos, 1);
    } 
    else {
      this.costCenter.splice(1);
    }
  }
```

El código funciona; pero está haciendo una búsqueda innecesaria; necesito saber la forma que no me haga esa búsqueda; sino que me ahorre la búsqueda; para lograr esto, se hace desde el template.

Por favor; ¿me podría decir cómo lo podría hacer desde el template?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, trata de reformularla, a ver si alguien puede ayudarte

Comment: No etiendo a que busqueda te refieres. Como te dice FederHico, reformula la pregunta  aver si podemos ayudarte.